# change date from m/d/Y to m-d-Y

Tags: php, date

So i have a small issue. I am using jquery datepicker to collect dates.
While users enter data, they see the following format mm/dd/yy
But I would like to convert that to m-d-Y in Php.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $time);
echo $date->format('m-d-Y');
```

Comment: +1 for actually using Date functions. Future proofing and considering other possibilities is important, and these other answers will only provide more work in the long run when that date format needs to change or be modified further.

Answer (score 0):

To "*change date from m/d/Y to m-d-Y*" you can just use `str_replace`

```
$date = '03/13/2013';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
```

If you need to change the format ie from `yy` to `Y`, try this:

```
$date = '03/13/13';
$date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($date));
```

[**See this demo**](http://codepad.org/kfqVyFes)

---

*References:*

[**str_replace()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), [**date()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [**strtotime()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: I tried that but i get this error @Mark M
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /home2/fairacre/public_html/resource-libs-files/classes/payments/booking.php on line 216

Comment: @JohnKariuki there is no call to `format()` in this answer, so your error is elsewhere

Comment: @JohnKariuki Not sure where you are getting `format()` from. It's not in my answer or your question. Maybe you posted your comment on the wrong answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = 'mm/dd/yy';
$a = str_replace('/', '-', $input);
echo $a;  // outputs mm-dd-yy
```

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please provide a little more information, background, references etc with your answers to avoid simply supplying a "code only" answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. In jQuery's datepicker, use the altFormat setting to show the user a date in one format (mm/dd/yy), but send the date in a different format (m-d-Y)
2. In PHP, convert the date, for example:

```
$incomingDate = "05/21/1979";

$newDate = date( "m-d-Y", strtotime( $date ) );

echo $newDate;
```